# get value of an input using jquery and onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selectlist

I have a dynamic table in which I can add many rows as needed using jquery.

On this rows there is a select list dropdown. This select has a list.
In function of the selected option, I try to do an ajax request and to apply the result in one of input of this rows.

The trouble I'm actually having is that I can not get the value of the selected list for the concerning rows. I added a class to the select list. The request is happening onchange but it can not get the value of the select list.

below is what I tried :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $().ready(function(){
            $('.debours_tva').change(function(e){
            var debours_id = $(this).closest("tr").find("input.debours_tva").val
            console.log(debours_id);
            var input = $(this).closest("tr").find("input.taux")
                $.ajax({
                url: 'requetes_ajax/check_taux_tva_debours.json.php',
                method: 'GET',
                data: 'debours_id=' + debours_id,
                success: function(returnData){
                    console.log(returnData);
                    if(returnData !=''){
                    input.removeAttr('value');
                    input.attr('value',returnData)
                    }else{

                    input.removeAttr('value');
                    input.attr('value',returnData)
                    }
                }, 
                dataType :'json'
                });
            });
            });
</script>
```

Actualy the problem met is that line

```
 var debours_id = $(this).closest("tr").find("input.debours_tva").val
```

that returns the following things instead of its value :

```
function ( value ) {
        var hooks, ret, isFunction,
            elem = this[0];

        if ( !arguments.length ) {
            if ( elem ) {
                hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

                if ( hooks && "get" in hooks && (ret = hooks.get( elem, "value" )) !== undefined ) {
                    return ret;
                }

                ret = elem.value;

                return typeof ret === "string" ?
                    // handle most common string cases
                    ret.replace(rreturn, "") :
                    // handle cases where value is null/undef or number
                    ret == null ? "" : ret;
            }

            return;
        }

        isFunction = jQuery.isFunction( value );

        return this.each(function( i ) {
            var val,
                self = jQuery(this);

            if ( this.nodeType !== 1 ) {
                return;
            }

            if ( isFunction ) {
                val = value.call( this, i, self.val() );
            } else {
                val = value;
            }

            // Treat null/undefined as ""; convert numbers to string
            if ( val == null ) {
                val = "";
            } else if ( typeof val === "number" ) {
                val += "";
            } else if ( jQuery.isArray( val ) ) {
                val = jQuery.map(val, function ( value ) {
                    return value == null ? "" : value + "";
                });
            }

            hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ this.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ this.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

            // If set returns undefined, fall back to normal setting
            if ( !hooks || !("set" in hooks) || hooks.set( this, val, "value" ) === undefined ) {
                this.value = val;
            }
        });
    }
```

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace

```
.val
```

by

```
.val()
```

The first expression returns the function which is responsible for getting the value. The second will execute it and actually returns the field's value.

Comment: thanks for that reply, but Actualy it returns to me "undefined" instead of the value

Comment: what if you replace `find("input.debours_tva").val` by `find(".debours_tva").val()` ?

Comment: this `var debours_id = $(this).closest("tr").find("debours_tva").val()
   console.log(debours_id);` returns to me "undefined"

Comment: you forgot the dot before 'debours_tva' : it should be `.find(".debours_tva")`

Comment: great, that works fine, thank you so much for your help, I just started yesterday to learn jquery and it is not often easy as it seems.